# Can't add objects to List in for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, foreach

How can I add objects to this list in for loop?

```
Transaction tx = currentSession.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria = currentSession.createCriteria(User.class);

List<User> list = criteria.list();
List<User> userList;

for(User user : list) {
    if(user.getAccountActivated() == 1) {
        userList.add(user);
    }
}
```

I tried the above, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know what's the issue here?

Comment: A) "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. B) If you try to compile that code, it tells you ***exactly*** what's wrong: *"variable userList might not have been initialized"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize `userList` like

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Or, if you use Java SE 7, `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: That's ok, everybody make mistakes, you should just read the compilers error output more carefully:)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize your `userList`.

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
```

If you're using Java 7, [you can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)  :

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you're using Java 8, you could use a [stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and filter the original list :

```
List<User> userList = list.stream()
                          .filter(u -> u.getAccountActivated() == 1)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```